# Compare 2 Images

Tags: javascript, optimization

I am using the following code to compare 2 images:

HTML (for example use only):

```
<canvas id="gViewCanvas"></canvas>
<img id="image1" src="image1.png" />
<img id="image2" src="image2.png" />
```

Javascript:

```
var gOldImage = document.getElementById("image1");
var gScreenImage = document.getElementById("image2");

var gViewCanvas = document.getElementById("gViewCanvas");
var gViewContext = gViewCanvas.getContext('2d');

var gGridSizeX = 1920;
var gGridSizeY = 32;
var nrX = Math.round(1920 / gGridSizeX);
var nrY = Math.round(955 / gGridSizeY);
gPixelCount = (gGridSizeX * gGridSizeY) * 4;




 function compareImages(img1, img2, pixelCount) {
   for (var i = 0; i < pixelCount; ++i) {
      if (img1.data[i] !== img2.data[i]) {
           return false;
        }
   }
   return true;
}



  var data, data2, BMPData, xpos, ypos, encoded, y, x;
//Iterate through lines of the image (width x 32)
  for (y = 0; y < nrY; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < nrX; x++) {

      xpos = x * gGridSizeX;
      ypos = y * gGridSizeY;
      //draw both sextions of images to the canvas and store pixel data in variables: data and data2
      gViewContext.drawImage(gOldImage, xpos, ypos, gGridSizeX, gGridSizeY, 0, 0, gGridSizeX, gGridSizeY);
      data = gViewContext.getImageData(0, 0, gGridSizeX, gGridSizeY);

      gViewContext.drawImage(gScreenImage, xpos, ypos, gGridSizeX, gGridSizeY, 0, 0, gGridSizeX, gGridSizeY);
      data2 = gViewContext.getImageData(0, 0, gGridSizeX, gGridSizeY);

      if (!compareImages(data, data2, gPixelCount)) {

        console.log("images are different");

      }else{
         console.log("same");             
      }
    }
  }
```

​
I am looking for any speed increases possible please.

I have already tested things such as:

- Methods of getting data from the canvas (toDataURL etc)
- different grid sizes (width * X is the faster than 32x32 etc)
- Drawing each image onto the canvas only once rather that inside the for loop (takes longer as canvas is bigger)

Any obvious things i've missed?

Comment: FYI, If you draw an image on a canvas from a different domain than your own, you can't use `getImageData`. In short, this code will not work if you change `image1.png` to `http://www.google.com/logo.png` (unless this script were to be run from `www.google.com`)

Comment: Yep thanks. In reality, I am actually getting a DataURL from a chrome extension, but the principal is the same :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of redrawing and getting new data for every pixel, just draw once and get both data arrays. Next loop through them and check their values:

```
var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
var c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d');
ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');

ctx1.fillRect(10, 10, 280, 280);
ctx2.fillRect(10, 10, 280, 280);

var data1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, c1.width, c1.height).data;
var data2 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, c2.width, c2.height).data;

var same = true;

for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    if (data1[i] !== data2[i]) {
        same = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SBDfz/1/